# sub-page settings saving in NETWORK DASHBOARD

Tags: multisite, sub-menu, add-submenu-page

In single WP installations, on a plugin's generated sub-page, you put

```
<form action="options.php" ...
```

does the job well.

However, in Multisite Network sub-page, `options.php` doesnt work, nor `settings.php` (it redirects to that page after form submission)...

I cant find out what page to use there, to send `<form>` values to that page which will save and redirect back to the sub-page ( like `options.php` does on single WP site- it saves values and redirects back).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is to set the form's `action=''` and use the `global $plugin_page;` as described in the **Notes** section of [add_submenu_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/).

For example:

```
add_action ('network_admin_menu', 'add_network_menus') ;

function
add_network_menus ()
{
    add_menu_page ('My Page Title', 'My Menu Title',
        'manage_network', 'my_menu_slug', 'my_network_admin_page') ;
    add_submenu_page ('my_menu_slug', 'Some Subpage Title',
        'My Submeny Title', 'manage_network', 'my_submenu_slug',
        'network_admin_subpage') ;

    return ;
}

function
network_admin_page ()
{
    global $title, $plugin_page ;

    echo <<<EOF
<div class='wrap'>
    <div id='icon-tools' class='icon32'></div>
    <h2>$title</h2>

    <p>more content here</p>
</div>
EOF;

    return ;
}

function
network_admin_subpage ()
{
    global $title, $plugin_page ;

    echo <<<EOF
<div class='wrap'>
    <div id='icon-tools' class='icon32'></div>
    <h2>$title</h2>

    <p>more content here</p>
    <form action='' method='GET'>
        <input type='hidden' name='page' value='$plugin_page' />
        <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
    </form>
</div>
EOF;

    return ;
}
```

This works for both normal and network admin menus.